# How to run OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: macos

My desktop computer basic configuration is Processor: AMD FX 8320, Motherboard: Asus M5A97, HD: WD Black, RAM: Kingston HyperX Fury DDR3 16GB, and Graphics Card: 2GB Saphire 5450.

VMware Workstation 12.5 is installed in my desktop computer.

I would like to run OS X 10.11 El Capitan as a Guest OS on VMware Workstation.

Please let me know and guide me.
Regards
GNS

Comment: Please search before posting questions. It literally took me less than a minute to find VMware's compatibility guide. Questions like this that are [basic customer service questions](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) are off-topic.

Comment: @GNS If you rephrase your question - remove any reference to non-Apple hardware - and mention that you want to run VMware Workstation 12.5  in a [boot-camped Windows](https://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) (i.e. a Windows on Macs), your question will be on-topic here and not against any SLA/EULA.

Answer (score 3):

Per VMware's [compatibility guide](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software), macOS (OS X) is not able to be installed as a Guest OS in Workstation.

On a side note, doing so would be against the OS X license agreement, since it prohibits running OS X on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: Hi..thank you for replying. I am aware of this fact. However..there are also some tech guys who are able to run OS X in this scenarios. Unfortunately, I am not in contact of them. That's why I put my question here. Please look for its alternate. The reason is .. I want to learn OS X.